# Dell Precision - screen blank after boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp

What are the relevant steps in troubleshooting a Dell Precision laptop that powers normally, produces a booting sound, and displays with a blank flikering screen.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is to plug an external monitor in to see if you get a picture on that. If so then you can narrow down the issues to probably being the display or connector on the laptop its-self. If the external monitor will not work then its more likely to be an on board graphics problem (We've had lots of this with Dell D620's recently) If so then depending on whether your laptop has a separate graphics boar, unlikely, then you will need to look at replacing the motherboard.

I would then test that all the connectors to the Laptops screen are seated properly in case any of them have been loosened (Unlikely but worth checking)

I would then want to try and test the LCD screen, it's hard if you don;t have an identical model but if you do then swap out the LCD screen and connectors from that one to see if it works.

If all this fails then take it down to your local laptop repair shop and inform them of the steps you have taken and they may be able to help you further.

Comment: The second most common spelling mistake on the internet. http://www.re-vision.com/spelling/separate.html